# how to use find() with two values

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement a function to return Paris with number and Lyon with number because I don't want to have a postal code.
But I have a problem it's doesn't work correctly for Lyon. It's only return Paris. I think my error it's on the line

```
(ci) => ci.postalCode === 75000 || 69000);
```

but I dont' know how to find the solution
If someone can explain me it's would be nice

Thanks

```
  public static CITIES_INFO = [
    { postalCode: 75000, baseName: "Paris" },
    { postalCode: 69000, baseName: "Lyon" },
    { postalCode: 33000, baseName: "bordeaux" },
    { postalCode: 44000, baseName: "nantes" },
    { postalCode: 38000, baseName: "grenoble" },
    { postalCode: 74000, baseName: "annecy" },
    { postalCode: 13000, baseName: "marseille" },
    { postalCode: 78000, baseName: "versailles" },
    { postalCode: 92081, baseName: "La Défense" },
    { postalCode: 92100, baseName: "boulogne" },
  ];

  public static convertPostalCodeToCityName(postalCode: number) {
    let cityInfo = CityUtils.CITIES_INFO.find((ci) => ci.postalCode === postalCode);
    if (cityInfo) {
      return cityInfo.baseName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cityInfo.baseName.slice(1);
    }

    if (postalCode > 75000 && postalCode < 76000 || (postalCode > 69000 && postalCode < 70000)) {
      cityInfo = CityUtils.CITIES_INFO.find(
        (ci) => ci.postalCode === 75000 || 69000);
      if (cityInfo) {
        const cityName = cityInfo.baseName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cityInfo.baseName.slice(1);
        return `${cityName} ${parseInt(postalCode.toString().slice(-2), 10)}`;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `ci.postalCode === 75000 || ci.postalCode === 69000`

Comment: FYI, you should use strings instead of numbers. Numbers will not retain a leading '0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare both values individually.

```
(ci) => ci.postalCode === 75000 || ci.postalCode === 69000);
```

Or a better way is to create an array and then use `includes()`

```
(ci) => [7500, 69000].includes(ci.postalCode));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @askemeline considering accepting the answer if you are satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const city = postalCode => CITIES_INFO.filter(code => code === postalCode).length !== 0 ? CITIES_INFO.find(code => code === postalCode)[0].baseName : null;
```

```
const baseName = city(75000)
```

Try this, it should return `baseName`